# autocomplete to list all available properties before the user starts typing

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

The default behavior of the autocomplete is the input field to be empty and to start listing data when the user starts typing. I want all the data to be listed as a dropdown in the beginning so the user can see all the available options. Is that possible:

html:

```
<input data-bind="kendoAutoComplete: { data: choices, value: selectedChoice }" />
<hr/>
Selected: <strong data-bind="text: selectedChoice"> </strong>
```

javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.choices = ko.observableArray(["apple", "orange", "banana"]);
   this.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/94/

Comment: This is not supported by the autocomplete widget. However you can subscribe on the focus event of the input and call a modified version of the `search` method (http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/autocomplete/display-all-possibilities-in-dropdown.aspx) which will open the dropdown with all the values.

Comment: If you want a visible list of all options, use a `<select>` with a `size` attribute instead of making other widgets behave in an unusual way.

Comment: @Tomalak, can You please provide a very simple demo of what You mean, for example in my fiddler, I have attached. Thanks!

Comment: I'm talking about the good old `<select size="3">` element with `<option>` s in it. These can be created with knockout's [`options` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html). I'm sure I don't need to spoon-feed you an example. ;) — Since Kendo does not seem to offer an own multi-line select widget, you could use the [ComboBox widget](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/ComboBox.html) and bind the `isOpen` property to `true`: `<input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { data: choices, value: selectedChoice, isOpen: true }" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do the trick by adding a `focus` event to the HTML `input` and then invoke `autocomplete.popup.open()`

Example:

HTML:

```
<input id="autocomplete" data-bind="kendoAutoComplete: { data: choices, value: selectedChoice }" />
<hr/>
Selected: <strong data-bind="text: selectedChoice"> </strong>
```

JavaScript

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.choices = ko.observableArray(["apple", "orange", "banana"]);
    this.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
$("#autocomplete").on("focus", function() {
    var autocomplete =    $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");
    autocomplete.popup.open();
});
```

and the JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2Qnv7/101/

Comment: The example you have posted does not seem to work. It is not listing all elements when you put focus on it.